# No database provider has been configured for this DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using two context, but now the need to create a RepositoryBase has arisen, but returns this error to me:

> 'No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.'  this.dbSet = context.Set()

**RepositoryBase**

```
 public class RepositoryBase<TEntity> : IDisposable where TEntity : class
{

    internal ApplicationDbContext2 context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;
    public RepositoryBase(ApplicationDbContext2 context) 
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }
```

**UnitOfWork**

```
public class UnitOfWork : DbContext, IDisposable
{
    private ApplicationDbContext2 context = new ApplicationDbContext2();
    private RepositoryBase<Album> albumRepository;
```

I put the beginning for you to see, how can I fix ?? I tried to add dbContext, but i couldn't run.

Comment: `"the need to create a RepositoryBase has arisen"` <= Why? The type `DbContext` is an implementation of a UoW pattern and the type `DbSet<T>` is an implementation of a Repository pattern. Why re-wrap these types in your own implementation of the same pattern? You are adding nothing of value, just more code and a poor abstraction which results in code that is harder to read, debug, and use. In short, I *strongly* recommend you re-think this (and don't do it).

Comment: @Igor Actually it's that I have a very extensive code that I'm bringing from another project, and it uses it that way, to avoid rework

Answer (score 0):

You have all except a DBContext class,
you should provide a DbContext with the needed DbSets and with the correct configuration if needed.
Please note also that you potentially will need an EntityConfiguration for each of your POCOs.
Or Else, if you have already dbcontext, then it is not well configured.